# WPF user control maximize on startup

Tags: wpf, xaml, authentication, startup

i have .xaml page named LoginView.xaml
But its not a exact User Control, this xaml page inherits to MvxWpfView & also MvxwpfView inherits inherits to User Control finally. & this is the start up page for me.
As Top of xaml Page like this & continuos on:

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" .....

My question is How can I maximize the MvxWpfView window / User control on the startup, i am not sure that much this is User Control or what.

Need Help,
Regards,
Praveen M

Comment: If you put this `Page` in the `MainWindow.xaml` then you need to maximize the window. UserControl hasn't got that ability, only `Windows` have. HTH

Comment: But my xaml starts like "<views:MvxWpfView & so on.." in this scenario what should i do.. Please suggest me

Comment: I think you are trying to run before you can walk. How good is your knowledge of WPF?

Comment: Apologies if I offended you, don't know how, I am not discouraging you from anything. If the login starts with `<views:MvxWpfView` try to find `WindowState` Property in your xaml. BTW This is my last post on this question, I don't want to get into any argument. Good luck.

Comment: @XAMIMAX, this is not inheriting to Window instead to User Control, i want to know How can i maximize the User control on startup. Replies always welcome. Got my Point.

Comment: Your `UserControl` is using whatever the size of it's parent. So if your login is inside of a `Grid` you should change the size of the grid. `UserControl` will only fit INTO a container. It hasn't got any capabilities of maximizing it self, however it does have `Width` and `Height` properties. HTH

Comment: Hey, i found the way to maximize the startup window, we need to check the App.xaml in the application directory.
Find the StartupUrl Property on same 
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" 
in my case it is Window so i declared WindowState="Maximize"
 
So it worked for me,
thanx